# Increase performance adb calls

Tags: android, python, cmd, adb

hello I need to send an adb touch event to 4-10 devices simulteaneously (or almost). To do that I'm doing this

```
subprocess.Popen("start cmd /c adb -s device1 shell input tap 350 530",shell=True)
subprocess.Popen("start cmd /c adb -s device2 shell input tap 350 530",shell=True)
subprocess.Popen("start cmd /c adb -s device3 shell input tap 350 530",shell=True)
subprocess.Popen("start cmd /c adb -s device4 shell input tap 350 530",shell=True)
```

It takes about 2-4sec to complete this sequence, Is there a faster way of do this?

Comment: Have you considered concurrency?

Comment: @TDG subprocesses are concurrent by definition

Comment: But how to implement concurrency in this specific case?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the shells from the call - you're starting a shell to run CMD (another shell) to run adb. Just don't put `shell=True` and remove CMD from the call.

```
for device in ['device1', 'device2', 'device3', 'device4']:
    subprocess.Popen(['adb', '-s', device, 'shell', 'input', 'tap', '350', '530'])
```

That's got to be faster because instead of invoking 3 processes per call, you invoke only one.